# NSMutableArray will not return/keep a sequence of NSNumbers

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, sequence

I would like, every time this function is called, that the NSMutableArray "sequence" to return the numbers already in the sequence, plus another random one from 0 to 3 at the end. This is the function I have so far:

**Edit** 
I tried calling initialising this function from inside didMoveToView and it now returns a sequence.
This code works now:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)extendSequence {

int newItem = arc4random_uniform(4);
NSNumber* newItemAsNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:newItem];
[sequence addObject:newItemAsNumber];
NSLog(@"%@", sequence);

return sequence;
}
```

(I am not sure where/if I could insert the `NSMutableArray *sequence = [NSMutableArray alloc] init]];` statement yet, because when I tried earlier, it wiped the sequence each time it was called.)

How could I achieve this?
A random sequence could return to be something like e.g. "1", then "1,3" then "1,3,0" etc.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are not initialized Mutable array. Do it inside your method on top.

Comment: Can you include the code that calls this method as well?

Comment: If you have a property called `sequence`, do _not_ call this method `sequence`! It will be seen as the getter for this property, and you will end up in confusion.

Comment: You can do if (!sequence){sequence = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];}, but you can also do the `alloc/init` before (depending on the life of your object, like in the `init` of your object).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are a little unclear on where you are keeping track of the "state" of what the sequence is so far. It sounds like you have an instance variable called "sequence" on this object somewhere (otherwise what you are writing now wouldn't compile). This is a reasonable place to keep track of this set of numbers, which will exist throughout the object's lifecycle, but adding to it each time the `-sequence` method is called.

You should add the initialization line for the array to your object's `-init` method. That way it is initialized just once with the object.

(The reason the current code returns `nil` is that you're *never* initializing the array, so the "additions" to it have no effect. The reason your other version, where you initialize within that method, kept wiping out the contents, is simply that you were creating and returning a fresh array every single time, which would replace the one you'd created the last time.)